# Understanding UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec in ArcPy script?

Tags: python, arcpy, cursor, arcgis-10.3, unicode

I work with arcmap 10.3 and python 2.7.8. I have more than 500 shapefiles that located in many folders and subFolders. All Sub Folders are located in one large directory. I try with arcpy to detect all  shapefiles that have in their attribute table ,in field name "YEUD", the value 20. I search all shape files that begin with letters "mig". Finally i tried to print all the shapefiles that had been found with value 20 in it.
When i run this code:

```
import arcpy,os,fnmatch,unicodedata,codecs

rootPath = r"C:\Project\layers"   
pattern = 'mig*.shp'   
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):   
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):   
        shp = os.path.join(root, filename)  
        if arcpy.ListFields(shp, "YEUD"):  
            print("{} has YEUD field".format(shp))   
            with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shp, ["YEUD"]) as rows:  
                for row in rows:  
                    if row[0] == 52:
                        print("{} has a record with YEUD = wanted row".format(shp))  
                        break
```

i get an error when the python meet files and folders with right to left font:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 23: invalid continuation byte
```

For completeness, i asked this question in https://geonet.esri.com/message/519769#519769 
and marked it as correct answer for files and folders names that written in left to right fonts ,but when i run this code i get an error when the python meet files and folders names with right to left fonts.

In GeoNet i didn't receive helpful answer. I also searched answers in stackOverflow but didn't understand how to unicode the script.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably trying to output Unicode characters into the terminal which does not know them. I'd suggest writing the results to a file instead, so that you can do something like this:

```
import arcpy,os,fnmatch,unicodedata,codecs

rootPath = r"C:\Project\layers"   
pattern = 'mig*.shp'   

with open('results.log', 'w') as logfile:
  for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):   
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):   
      shp = os.path.join(root, filename)  
      if arcpy.ListFields(shp, "YEUD"):  
        logfile.write(u"{} has YEUD field\n".format(shp).encode('utf8'))
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shp, ["YEUD"]) as rows:
          for row in rows:  
            if row[0] == 52:
              logfile.write(u"{} has a record with YEUD = wanted row".format(shp).encode('utf8')) 
              break
```

I don't have any files to test if it works, though. You might want to use a different encoding than `utf8` if it does not work (probably your national encoding).

Comment: i get en error: >>> 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yaron.KAYAMOT\Desktop\python.py", line 11, in <module>
    logfile.write(u"{} has YEUD field\n".format(shp).encode('utf8'))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 23: ordinal not in range(128)
>>>